# Math.random() generates same number Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to make a random number generator in JS and I cannot generate one. All the time it returns the same number 2 or 0 (If I change the number)
here's the code:

```js
function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  console.log(randomNumber);
}

nextSequence();
nextSequence();
nextSequence();
nextSequence();
nextSequence();
nextSequence();
nextSequence();
nextSequence();
```

Comment: [Seems to work fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/3munctak/).

Comment: Works well for me too. Is it exactly the same code? Add more details about the environment you are running it in, maybe that will help.

Comment: I'm sure. I even made a link of my last comment that you can try for yourself. That function is called 25 times and I get random results logged to the console. If you get the same number, it is likely an issue elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Your range of number is rather small [0-3] so there's a 25% * 25% chance you will get the same number twice in theory, but it seems much more likely probably because `Math.random` is not perfectly random.

Comment: It works here too. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I'm getting 0 now

Comment: I ran this code in the debugger console on Chrome 91 -- I pasted the code into the console and ran the function. I got: 2,2,3,2,0,3,0,1,1,0,1,3. Maybe you just ran into a lucky/unlucky sequence?

Comment: no man i don't have any code in my js file other than this

Comment: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: var output= Math.random()
output= Math.floor( output * 100);
 this code in from another file (when i was 5 day old beginner)
and it works perfectly

Comment: This code works perfectly also.

Comment: chrome is running really slow today maybe that indicates the browser has a problem

Comment: The JSFlidde and the code here in the snippet in your question are also executed in your own browser. If it is a browser related issue, you would've been able to reproduce it here as well.

Comment: i ran this edge same output always 0

Comment: @MuntahaHasan How can we help when we can't reproduce the problem?  The code snippet Pointy edited into your question works as it should for the rest of us.  If it doesn't work for you, we're left with the conclusion that it's a problem with your browser, or a machine configuration problem if it fails on multiple browsers.

Comment: ehhhh okay i understood

Comment: i think it is a problem in my machine

Comment: as it doesn't work in any of the browsers it is a problem in my pc

Comment: @Ivar Pointy Tushar Shahi Patrick Chu and everybody who helped me a big thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. To add to my comment above, a screenshot from my Chrome 91 debugger console:

[image: screenshot from debugger console session]

Answer (score -2):

you didn't [call the function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp).

```
      function nextSequence() {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        console.log(randomNumber);
      }
      nextSequence()
```

Answer (score -2):

i once run into this problem, The Desire way to Create Random number in java/js is this

```
int rand=Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min
```